# RXJS operator for combineLatest with no null values

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, ngrx, ngrx-store

In my Angular project, I am trying to get the values of a few **ngrx selectors**, and use them all to create a query string to use for an API call.

I want to wait until they all emit a non nullish value, and then emit only once (so the api call is not sent multiple times if the values change over time).
This is the solution I got to:

```
const selectorA$ = this.store.select(...)
const selectorB$ = this.store.select(...)
const selectorC$ = this.store.select(...)

return combineLates([selectorA$, selectorB$, selectorC$]).pipe(
   first(list => list.every(item => item != null)),
   map(([selectorA, selectorB, selectorC]) => //... return query string using the store values)
)
```

I am wondering if this is a right approach or is there a built in rxjs operator that can give me this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never do that:

```
const selectorA$ = this.store.select(...)
const selectorB$ = this.store.select(...)
const selectorC$ = this.store.select(...)

return combineLatest([selectorA$, selectorB$, selectorC$]).pipe(...)
```

Imagine you've got an action dispatched that affects the state (once) and all your selectors here rely on that state and the 3 of them are updated (still at once). Every time your selectors get updated your `combineLatest` will emit (at least after they've all emitted initially, which with ngrx store will happen straight away as you always get an emission as soon as you subscribe to the state).

So your `combineLatest` will potentially trigger 3 times instead of one (after init) when there's a new state update.

How to solve this? Create a new select that combines the 3 values you want. It'll only emit once when needed.

```js
export const abc = createSelector(selectorA, selectorB, selectorC, (a, b, c) => ({ a, b, c }))
```

And replace

```js
const selectorA$ = this.store.select(...)
const selectorB$ = this.store.select(...)
const selectorC$ = this.store.select(...)

return combineLatest([selectorA$, selectorB$, selectorC$]).pipe(...)
```

With

```js
this.store.select(abc)
```

Comment: When using your approach I still get the values as undefined, how can I make sure I only use them when they are ready?

Comment: You can still add a `filter(list => list.every(item => item != null))` followed by a `first()` or `take(1)`

Answer (score 4):

You can just use [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) with [`filter`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter) to allow the stream to proceed only when all three values are present!

If you want only the first instance, we can use [`takeUntil`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takeuntil) to complete the stream, when the first valid input is emitted!

```
private destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

const selectorA$ = this.store.select(...)
const selectorB$ = this.store.select(...)
const selectorC$ = this.store.select(...)

return combineLatest([selectorA$, selectorB$, selectorC$]).pipe(
   filter(list => list.every(item => item != null)),
   takeUntil(this.destroy$)
   map(([selectorA, selectorB, selectorC]) => { 
        // since we want only the first instance of valid input, we complete the subject, so that the stream is completed and no other events are taken! we use takeUntil for this!
        this.destroy$.next();
        this.destroy$.complete();
   })
)
```

Comment: Why having a subject, a takeUntil and a map with side effect instead of `first()` or `take(1)`?

Comment: @maxime1992 because question requirement is the proper combination of all three observables as not null, then only stop listening for events! so I used takeUntil

Comment: @AdiFuchs Does this answer solve your issue?

Comment: Might solve but I changed it up as @maxime1992 said. so I am now using a combined selector + first. I hope that is a good approach

Comment: @AdiFuchs no issues, thanks for your time!

Comment: @NarenMurali just to answer to your last reply, it's still fine though. `combineLatest([selectorA$, selectorB$, selectorC$]).pipe(filter(list => list.every(item => item != null)), first())`. No need for a class variable external to the stream, a takeuntil and manually destroy/complete the subject in a map. The first will close the stream as soon as it gets a value, which only happens after the filter meaning it'll be valid at that point